# A C++ program with user-defined variables

Tags: c++, templates, calculator

I'm writing a code that implements simple command line calculator, and I wanted to add a function for user to create his own variables with numeric values for better calculations. Can anyone share any advice, what technique should I use? I thought about creating an allocated two-dimensional string array and later just converting numeric values or use a template, something like that:

```
template<class T>
void UserVariables(T varname, T varvalue){
T tArray[2][MAX_VARS]={ {varname1, varvalue1}, {varname2, varvalue2}, ... };
....
}
```

Maybe there are any better and less noobie-ish decisions out there? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I personally would use a `std::map` that translates from the `name` to `value` (where `value` is of whatever type your calculator uses, e.g. `double`).

Comment: You don't want `varname` to have type `T`, surely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options are here:

[std::unordered_map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/)

[std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)

[std::unordered_multimap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_multimap/)

[std::multimap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/)

Comment: What about `vector<pair<string, double>>` or `list` or boost stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how your attempt would work - templates are evaluated at compile time, not run time, so the user can't make new variables one the code is running.